# How to restore a database removing the filestream data

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I have a 50GB SQL Server 2008R2 database backup.

I'd like to restore only the "tables" and not the filestream data (the blobs saved as filestream).

This is because I fon't have 100GB free (50 needed to copy the file on the server, 50 to restore the db).

Is there a switch  for the `restore` command to avoid restoring filestream blobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot restore specific structures from a SQL Server backup; it's all or nothing.  Your best bet is to try scripting out the data using a third party tool or using the generate scripts option SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Thank you.  So i must Force mi sysadmin to governo me 100GB.